# How can I compare 2 codes ignoring the changes on name of variable?

Tags: c, compare, review, beyondcompare

in my daily works, I generate C codes from Matlab Simulink models.
but everytime I generate codes from the same model, the variable name is changed slightly.
[screenshot]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoybH.png

```
//old
s32 rtb_DataTypeConversion_ab;

//new
s32 rtb_DataTypeConversion_cd; //only name has changed slightly (ab->cd)
```

How can I compare codes without noticing these change?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such functionality supported by BCompare. Copy the code out of files to new tab and replace one to another, one-by-one, (which you think are same variable).  When you repeat this 3-5 times, red regions will disappear a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare Pro Edition can ignore variable name changes. Feature not supported in Beyond Compare Standard Edition.

In Beyond Compare's Text Compare:

1. Load the old file (rtb_DataTypeConversion_ab) on the left and the new file (rtb_DataTypeConversion_cd) on the right.
2. Click the **Rules** toolbar button (referee icon).
3. Go to the **Replacements** tab.
4. Click **+**.
5. **Text to find**: rtb_DataTypeConversion_ab
6. **Replace with**: rtb_DataTypeConversion_cd
7. Click OK until you're back to the main window.

If **View > Ignore Unimportant Differences** is on, the variable rename will show as a match, if it is off it will show in blue.